# Storageclass.storage.k8s.io "gp2-encrypted" not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm attempting to create add a storage class for my pod but I'm receiving the error in the title when using `helm install` to generate it. I can confirm that the same yaml file creates the storage class when using `kubectl apply -f` instead of `helm install`. Here is the output for `kubectl describe pvc data-opendistro-es-en-us-master-0` and I've attached the yaml file for the storage class right after.

```html
Name:          data-opendistro-es-en-us-master-0
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  gp2-encrypted
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app=opendistro-es-en-us
               chart=opendistro-es-en-us-0.1
               heritage=Helm
               release=opendistro-es-en-us
               role=master
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    opendistro-es-en-us-master-0
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                  From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                 ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  73s (x383 over 96m)  persistentvolume-controller  storageclass.storage.k8s.io "gp2-encrypted" not found
```

```html
# Copyright 2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0

---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: data-gp2
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  encrypted: "true"
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```

Comment: the StorageClass's `metadata.name` very clearly says `data-gp2` yet the PVC says `gp2-encrypted` -- is there something else that you're asking?

Comment: `StorageClass:  gp2-encrypted` is coming from selecting `type: gp2`. I'm not sure what that has to do with the name of the Storage class. I'm asking why I get the `"gp2-encrypted" not found ` error with helm install but not with kubectl apply

Comment: @AnthonyHarley, i'm getting the same error, may i know how you fixed it?

Comment: I was getting a similar error. I'm creating the persistent volume and persistent volume claim in the same helmfile as my statefulset. I deleted my statefulset using `kubectl delete ...`, and when I tried to run `helmfile apply -f <file>` I was getting `storageclass.storage.k8s.io "encrypted-gp3" not found`. Since this was only dev I ran `helmfile delete -f <file>` and destroyed the whole release. Then I could run `apply` again and everything came back up. Not great, but got me unstuck and maybe will help somebody else.